# strange cache issue : FireFox4

Tags: javascript, firefox, caching

Today i StumbleUpon a strange cache behavior of Firefox 4 which is described bellow.

1. There is a form

   ```
   <form name="widget">
   <input type="hidden" name="position" value="-1" />
   </form>
   ```
2. On an arbitrary event i have changed it to say "rss".
3. After refreshing the page using "F5", i access the value of

   ```
   alert(document.widget.position.value);
   ```

   which is returning "**rss**". WHY THE OLD VALUE?
4. But after refreshing the page using "Control+F5", i access the value of

   ```
   alert(document.widget.position.value);
   ```

   which is returning correct "**-1**". WHY NOT FIRST TIME?

I am really confused by this behavior.

**NOTE:** Only FireFox4 is doing it, chrome i fine but did not tested on ie.

Comment: Confirmed, I think it's a cache bug...

Comment: It's looks like forms autocompletion feature bug.

Comment: What is your "arbitrary event"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's [FF's caching](http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?f=25&t=470306&start=0&st=0&sk=t&sd=a) of forms/input element values that's bugging you. You may want to use:

```
<form id="widget">
 <input type="hidden" id="position" value="-1" />
</form>
```

and to change the value:

```
 document.getElementById('position').value = /*[your value]*/;
```

Furthermore `<form ... autocomplete="off">` seems to work.

Comment: +1, Thanks for your reply, I am pretty confident about the form auto-complete thing because when i go to the source code in browser its fine. And also the firefox don't suck that much in caching. I hopefully will test it on my next sitting.

Comment: Thanks dude, it was form auto-complete.